# Cart functionality in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

So here I have Cart functionality inside of the Context. The thing I am trying to achieve is this. I want to only add items of the same id 1 time into the cart. And when I press the add to cart button, instead of add to cart text, it should be an item added or smth. How would I approach it?

```
import React from "react";

function getCartFromLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.getItem("cart")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    : [];
}

const CartContext = React.createContext({});

function CartProvider({ children }) {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState(getCartFromLocalStorage());
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = React.useState(0);

  function onUpdate() {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));

    console.log(cart);
    const newTotal = cart.reduce(
      (total, cartItem) => total + cartItem.amount * cartItem.price,
      0
    );
    setTotal(newTotal);

    const newCartItems = cart.reduce(
      (total, cartItem) => total + cartItem.amount,
      0
    );
    setCartItems(newCartItems);
  }
  React.useEffect(onUpdate, [cart]);

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    setCart([...cart].filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };


  /* add to cart */
  const addToCart = (book) => {
    const { id, image, bookName, by } = book;
    let item = cart.find((item) => item.id === id);
    if (item) {
      item.amount++;
      onUpdate();
    } else {
      setCart(
        cart.concat({
          amount: 0,
          price: parseFloat(book.RegularPrice.replace("$", "")),
      
          ...book
        })
      );
    }
  };

  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        cart,
        cartItems,
        total,
        removeItem,
        addToCart,
        clearCart
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}
export { CartContext, CartProvider };
```

```
import React,{useContext, } from 'react'
import { CartContext } from '../../context/cart';
import HoverBooks from './HoverBooks';
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from '../../context/user';
const Books = ({category}) => {
const {addToCart }= useContext(CartContext)
const { user } = React.useContext(UserContext);

    return (     
        <div className='books__main'>      
        {category.slice(0, 5).map((book) => {   
          console.log(book)    
          return(
           <React.Fragment key={book.id}> 
           <div className='book__content'>
            <li className='book__name'>{book.bookName}</li>
             <h4 className='book__prop'>By: {book.by}</h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Narreted by: {book.Narreted || book["Narreted by"]}</h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Length: {book.length || book["Length"]}</h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Release Date: {book.ReleaseDate}</h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Language: {book.Language}</h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Rating: {book.rating}</h4>
           </div>           
           <div className='book__adt'> 
           <h4>Regular Price: ${book.RegularPrice}</h4>
           {user.authToken ? (
           <button onClick={() => 
              addToCart(book)
           }
           >Add to cart</button>  
           ) : (
            <Link to="/login" className="adt__login">
            Login to buy books
           </Link>
        )}
           </div>
       </React.Fragment>
        )})}
      </div>
     
    )
}
export default Books
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?  If things are not working as expected, please explain what you are seeing.

Comment: @MattMorgan Right now I can add the same item numerous times, but I am trying to add functionality so, I can only add an item 1 time into the cart, are you understanding me

Comment: What is your `find` function returning?  Do you get an `item` when you expect to?  What does that `item` look like?

Comment: here is the sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sound-5y7pg?file=/src/BookContext.js so you can nderstand better